# Transact SQL UPDATE based on a declared variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables called `ALUMNO` and `ALUMNO_GENERAL`.

I would like to create a stored procedure which automatically chooses which table will update by looking at the variable `@campo` declared as a parameter to the stored procedure.

When I execute the procedure below, it says `1 row affected`, but does not update the value of the table.

```
exec updateAl 'CALLE','0015','ROJO'
```

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure updateAl

    @campo varchar(30), @matr varchar(10), @newVal varchar(15)
    as begin

    if @campo  IN ('AP_PATERNO' , 'AP_MATERNO', 'NOMBRE', 'GRUPO', 'TURNO' , 'SEMESTRE' , 'STATUS' , 'NUMEMPLEADO') 

    begin
        select @campo
        declare @sql varchar (1000)

        select @sql= 'update alumno set '+ @campo+'='+@newVal +' where MATRICULA='+@matr
        exec(@sql)
    end
    else
         update ALUMNO_GENERAL set @campo =@newVal where MATRICULA=@matr
end
```

Comment: You second statement in the `else` isn't going to work as-is. So if your `@campo` is causing it go to the `else` then you'll have to fix that up to be dynamic as well.

Comment: I hope you are not going to use this in a web application; [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) is close...

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space.

Comment: My guess would be that you have a UI that auto-saves each field after you leave it (inline editing kind-of-thing), and you don't want to write a separate SQL statement for each field to do the updating. There are definitely alternatives and frameworks that would help you with this. You are setting yourself up for a maintenance nightmare with procedures like this.

Comment: this is a practice in my school, and I just thought about that to save code..

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamic sql is not correct, try this:

```
select @sql= 'update alumno set '+ @campo+'='''+@newVal +''' where MATRICULA='''+@matr + '''
exec(@sql)
end
```

Comment: Probably need extra quotes around `@matr` as well, since it's also a `varchar`.

Comment: it doesn't works :/ also shows the message "1 row(s) affected" but doesn't update the value on the table.. Any idea?